# Using qsort() with Structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, qsort

I just started learning C and I'm still new to it. 
In this program I'm working with an array of structs. The structs are:

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} Date;

typedef struct {
    int serial_num;
    char full_name[15];
    Date *pDate;
} Person;
```

The array is `Person *people`.

Now I have two arrays of people and birth dates of those people (same indexes):

```
const char* names[MAX] = { "Sasson_Sassoni", "Pooh", "James_Bond", "Elvis_is_Alive", "Shilgiya", "Cleopatra", "Sissoo_VeSimmhoo" };

const int dates[MAX][COLS] = {
        { 10, 1, 1988 },
        { 12, 12, 1948 },
        { 4, 12, 1970 },
        { 11, 11, 1890 },
        { 11, 11, 1948 },
        { 1, 10, 1213 },
        { 12, 11, 1948 }
    };
```

By using `switch case`, every time the user types 1 a person from the lists (Name and birthday) is added to the list `people`. Then if the user types 3, the list `people` should be sorted by date (oldest to youngest). So I wrote the following two functions:

```
void sortList(Person **people, int index) {
    qsort(*people, index, sizeof(Person), intcmp);
}
int intcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    Person *one = (Person *)a;
    Person *two = (Person *)b;
    int year1 = one->pDate->year;
    int year2 = two->pDate->year;
    int month1 = one->pDate->month;
    int month2 = two->pDate->month;
    int day1 = one->pDate->day;
    int day2 = two->pDate->day;
    if (year1 > year2)
        return -1;
    else if (year2 > year1)
        return 1;
    if (month1 > month2)
        return -1;
    else if (month2 > month1)
        return 1;
    if (day1 > day2)
        return -1;
    else if (day2 > day1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But every time I get an error saying:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
one->pDate was nullptr.
```

Any help?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Further explanation: In order to insert the people to the array one by one, I made a variable called index and every time a person is added the index grows by one. So When calling the function qsort(), `index` is the number of people in the array. Also `MAX=7, COLS=3, LEN=10`. The function that adds people to the array is:

```
void addToList(Person **people, int *index, const char *names[MAX], const int dates[][COLS]) {
    people[*index] = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    people[*index]->serial_num = *index + 1;
    strcpy(people[*index]->full_name, names[*index]);
    Date *temp = (Date *)malloc(sizeof(Date));
    temp->day = dates[*index][0];
    temp->month = dates[*index][1];
    temp->year = dates[*index][2];
    people[*index]->pDate = temp;
    printf("%d %s     %d/%d/%d \n", people[*index]->serial_num, people[*index]->full_name, people[*index]->pDate->day, people[*index]->pDate->month, people[*index]->pDate->year);
    *index = *index + 1;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is the value of `index` for example, what is `people` ?

Comment: show us the code that populates the array `people`

Comment: Sorry, added the variables and the function that populates `people`.

Comment: @Stargateur - Kinda jumped that gun, don't you think? This message is from the run-time. It has nothing to do with the language this is being compiled as.

Comment: @Stargateur: I guess I should ask you and not OP, since you edited the tags. Why C++? It looks like C to me.

Comment: I said why in edit message feel free to disagree. For me the OP code in c++ environment.

Comment: @Stargateur - It very well could be (maybe even a bit likely). But I think we should clarify with him.

Comment: @eitanmayer - To help us figure this out once and for all, does `char *c = malloc(1);` compile as is in your program, or do you have to add a cast?

Comment: I'm working in a C++ environment in Visual Studios but the code is supposed to be C language because that is what I'm studying. As for `char *c = malloc(1);`, it does not compile and I have to add a cast.

Comment: @eitanmayer - The compiler used can affect the semantics! Use a C compiler, not a C++ one. If you haven't yet, switch your project to C mode.

Comment: You should have a function which prints out the data in your array.  You should use that function before calling the sort to ensure your data is set up correctly. Then you can be more confident about what your sorting is up to.

Comment: eitanmayer Consider meeting someone who is 1) having trouble with C code and 2) reports they are not using a C compiler.  [@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671131/using-qsort-with-structs#comment80291546_46671131) is quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mcve is not complete but I think it's because you confuse pointer and struct:

```
void sortList(Person **people, int index) {
    qsort(people, index, sizeof(Person *), intcmp);
    // or qsort(people, index, sizeof *people, intcmp);
}

int intcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Person *one = *(const Person **)a;
    const Person *two = *(const Person **)b;
```

Comment: Wow that worked! I've been stuck on this a while, thanks!

Comment: BTW, good use of `const` and not using `Person *one = *(Person **)a;`