# Sorting patient struct by born date

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I have a struct

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int born_date;
}patient;
```

I have to write a function that will be sorting this array by born date.
The function look like 
`void rendez(patient patients[], int n) {}` Where the n number is the array length & patients[] array include the data about the patients.
I know this not a hard task  but I learning this language still (C).
I can use the qsort function but this is new for me.
I listen every tipps & thanks for helping

Comment: Try starting by iterating over all the elements in the array and print them. After that you can add extra logic in the for loop to keep the highest/lowest born_date and its index in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using qsort() with Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671131/using-qsort-with-structs)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Learning is needs practicing. Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. If you already found `qsort` maybe you try to use it and show us what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qsort works with a user-defind compare. You will need a helper function to compare 2 items

```
int compare_patient_dob(void *a, void *b)
{
    patient *pa = (patient *) a ;
    patient *pb = (patient *) b ;

    // Assuming born_dates are comparable, e.g., YYYYMMDD
    return pa->born_date - pb->born_date ;
}
...
// Later in the rendez function.
    qsort(patients, n, sizeof(patients[0], compare_patient_dob) ;
```

Comment: And this task without qsort is possible to make ?

Comment: You can write your own sort. In this case, consider simpler to implement (less efficient sor) - e.g., bubble sort, etc.

Comment: @dash-o, you don't need the casts to `(patient *)`, it's better to let the compiler check for the proper pointer types, than forcing a cast that can hide a mistake in future modifications.

Comment: In "C", there is not data at run-time to validate casting. Compare this with Java, C# and other language, where object class can be determined at run time. If you do not explicitly cast the void * pointers into 'patient *', the code will not compile. If you change the pointer in the prototype to 'client *', it will not match the prototype of qsort.